# Regular expression revision

Tags: regex, lexical

Question: Given a binary alphabet `{0,1}`, write a regular expression that recognises all words
that have at least two consecutive ’1’s, for example `0100110`, `0111`, `00010011001`.

My attempt at an answer is: `0*{ (0|1)* 11+ }*`

Comment: What about [`[01]*11[01]*`](https://regex101.com/r/fF0gK0/1)?

Comment: If this question is about regular expressions as in automata theory, The site for that is http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple expression like

```
[01]*11[01]*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fF0gK0/1)

**Explanation**:

- `[01]*` - zero or more zeros or ones
- `11` - two consecutive `1`s
- `[01]*` - zero or more zeros or ones

Answer (score 1):

If the alphabet is a given, so that you don't have to account for any symbol not in the language, and you're matching words one a time, so that you don't have to worry about word beginnings and endings, it's easy.

```
.*?11
```

We reluctantly match everything up until we find two consecutive 1s. Then we know the word we're matching is one we're interested in.

---

*However*, I get the feeling this doesn't answer your question. Something tells me you're working with a very restricted flavour that does not allow for reluctance (matching as little as possible with `*?`) nor for promiscuity (matching "whatever" with `.`).

So instead, think of your regular expression as being in two possible states. The first is the unsatisfied state, where we haven't matched two consecutive 1s, and the second is the satisfied state, where we *have*.

1. As long as we match 0s, or a 1 followed by a 0, we remain in the unsatisfied state. This is `(0|10)*`.
2. Then we match two consecutive 1s and get to the satisfied state. This is `11`.
3. After that, we can match both 0s and 1s and remain in the satisfied state. This is `(0|1)*`. If you have character classes in your flavour, you can use those, as `[01]*`.

Putting it all together, we get

```
(0|10)*11(0|1)*
```

Which can be seen in action on [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/pZ3kX5/2).